# Error in html when accessing a property of an inherited interface. Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

i'm working with angular 17 and i have the following question:

I have an IDetails interface, which has some properties:

```
export interface IDetails {
  summary: Summary;
  description: string;
}
```

and I have another interface, which inherits from IDetails and implements a new property, which is specific to it.

```
export interface ICertificate extends IDetails {
  url: string;
}
```

In my Angular component, I receive an array of this interface via input:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input({required: true}) public inputDetail: Array<IDetails> = [];
}
```

Now, in html, when receiving this array, I do a for loop, and pass the url field to a child component

```
@for (item of inputDetail; track $index) {
    ...
      @defer (on viewport) {
        <app-validation [inputValidation]="**item?.url**"></app-validation>
      } @placeholder {
        <section>
          <h4>Loading...</h4>
        </section>
      } @error {
        <section>
          <h4>Error, Try Again.</h4>
        </section>
      }
}
```

And it is on this line where I try to pass the url property, that the error occurs:

> Property 'url' does not exist on type 'IDetails | ICertificate'.
> Property 'url' does not exist on type 'IDetails'

How can I resolve this issue and correctly access and send the property to the child component?

I tried putting two types of values into this received property. No success.

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input({required: true}) public inputDetail: Array<IDetails> | Array<ICertificate> = [];
}
```

Comment: Unless the object is `ICertificate`. As the error mentioned clearly, the `url` field does not exist in the `IDetails` type.

Comment: @YongShun So does that mean I won't be able to work this way with the interfaces? This is a very common practice for projects I work on in .NET, I have the car mother class, and then I implement Camaro and Mustang, and I can correctly access their properties.

Comment: No, this is the same with TypeScript too. Definitely, you can't access the member from the base/parent class that only exists in the child/derived class. You will get the compilation error when you are accessing the property/field that doesn't exist in the interface/class. You need to **downcast** to specific class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly use `ICertificate` on the details component, since the property might or might not be there, set the url property with `?` so that null and undefined are allowed, now you can directly use `ICertificate` without worrying about the other interface!

```
export interface ICertificate extends IDetails {
  url?: string;              // <- changed here!
}
```

To get rid of the compiler error, just give empty string as a check for  the `@Input` so that the error goes away!

```
@for (item of inputDetail; track $index) { @defer (on viewport) {
<app-validation [inputValidation]="item.url || ''"></app-validation> <!-- changed here -->
} @placeholder {
<section>
  <h4>Loading...</h4>
</section>
} @error {
<section>
  <h4>Error, Try Again.</h4>
</section>
} }
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bszqcl?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fvalidation%2Fvalidation.component.ts,src%2Fdetails%2Fdetails.component.ts,src%2Fdetails%2Fdetails.component.html,src%2Fvalidation%2Fvalidation.component.html,src%2Fdetails%2Fdetails.component.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Well, I managed to understand and it helped me solve the problem in this case.
But what would happen if I had two interfaces that inherit from Details and have different properties? In this case, I wouldn't be able to work on them in this component, right?

Comment: @Bazz Set the properties with `?:` so that you can use the same base interface with any number of child interfaces, Could you show me the scenario on the stackblitz I shared, I will suggest a fix for it

Comment: @Bazz as long as you dont use the base interface directly and always use the child interfaces you wont have issues, if you want to use multiple types you can chain the child types like so `: Array<ICertificate | Interface2 | Interface3>`

Comment: Dude, you saved me, I wouldn't be able to sleep without knowing how to do that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, setup a [non-nullish assert operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-and-non-undefined-type-guards):

```
export interface ICertificate extends IDetails {
  url?: string;
}
```

Second step is to use the proper interface which has actually url property, so you cannot use IDetails as array and expect to access url. Because IDetails doesn't have url property.
So replacing IDetails and keeping just ICertificate:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input({required: true}) public inputDetail: Array<ICertificate> = [];
}
```

If you get a error that says inputValidation can be undefined, then you have to work on your child component:

```
 <app-validation [inputValidation]="item.url"></app-validation>
```

This will give item.url, but setting it with `?` as operator, will tell that it can be undefined or null.

To fix this you have to adjust the child component and that's based on your expectation about the dataflow.

If the child component should have a default, you can set that up:

```
export class ChildComp {
  @Input() public inputValidation: ICertificate['url'] = '';
}
```

Playground here working example here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17-starter-project-ywads6?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the links to read more on the subject. I would just ask you to fix the stackblitz link, at least for me it's not working. 
And I ask you too, if I had two interfaces that inherit from details, with different properties, I wouldn't be able to work with this solution, any ideas? (just asking out of curiosity and for the challenge hehe, the problem was solved)

Comment: Thanks for making me notice about the link, i'm going to update it. I think you got the answer you were looking for in the comments to the other answer, otherwise you can make a use-case and create a new question about it. Interesting questions are always welcome as they challenge but also make us grow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using TypeScript's type assertion

```
<app-validation [inputValidation]="(item as ICertificate).url"></app-
```

Comment: Thanks for your help friend, unfortunately it didn't work, but it helped me understand where I was going wrong.